# Put 1000 vectors into a list

Tags: r, list

I have 1000 vectors: `c1,c2,...,c1000`

I want to put them in a list looks like:

```
list1<-list(c1,c2,...,c1000)
```

How can I do it in a loop please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `mget` on a vector of strings created using `paste`.  The output will be a `list` with list elements as the values stored in the object names.

```
list1 <- mget(paste0('c', 1:1000))
```

If we need to remove the vector object names from the global environment,

```
rm(list=paste0('c', 1:1000))
```

as @Frank mentioned in the comments.

Comment: And then `rm(list=paste0('c', 1:1000))` to clean up, I'd say.